# Inverse logit/sigmoid algebraic manipulations in Ian Goodfellow's Deep Learning Book derivation

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

In Ian Goodfellow's deep learning book page 177, the authors motivate the functional form of the sigmoid by normalizing $z$, a linear function of hidden units $h$, $z = w^T h + b$.

Unnormalized, $log(P(y)) = yz$

Exponentiating both sides and normalizing:

$P(y) = exp(yz) / \sum_{y'=0}^1 exp(y' z) = \sigma((2 y - 1) z)$

Where $\sigma$ is defined as

$\sigma(x) = exp(x)/(exp(x) + 1)$

Can someone explain where the $(2 y - 1) z$ comes from? Probably missing some simple algebra but I'm obtuse.

Comment: Another hint is that $x = xy + x(1-y)$, where $y=0$ or $y=1$.

Comment: The key point is to notice that y can only take two values : 0 or 1. Then by plugging it, we obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two notes before begin:

- I will treat this question as [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study).
- For reference, this is page 183 in Chapter 6 (equations 6.20-6.23) in the [online version](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) of the book.

First note that the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) simplifies to
$$\sigma[x]=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Then note that, expanding the sum, the expression for normalized probability
$$P[y]=\frac{e^{yz}}{1+e^z}$$
where $y\in\{0,1\}$

Finally, note that
$$2y-1=y-(1-y)$$.

because $y\in\{0,1\}$
when $y=1, $$2y-1=1$, then $$\sigma[((2y-1)z)]=\sigma[z]$$

when $y=0, $$2y-1=-1$, then $$\sigma[((2y-1)z)]=\sigma[-z]$$

And these two equations correspond to the equation
$$P[y]=\frac{e^{yz}}{1+e^z}$$
when $y=1$ and $y=0$.

Does this help?

Comment: not really... still can't understand how σ((2y-1)z) equals to exp(yz)/(1+exp(z)). In fact I think here the derivation is wrong.